# How to get GitHub Pages to work with the app domain name?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

I deployed a React app on gh-pages. The problem is that the URL (`https://username.io/react-app-name`) doesn't work because the app doesn't have a route to `react-app-name`. It has to be just `/` or `/users` etc. So by this kind of error loads a "not found" page. The not found page has a "go back home" button, which takes me to the homepage `/`, and from there the app works.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you might have missed setting the `homepage` property properly in your `package.json` file.

Here is how to do so:

1. Open your `package.json` file.
2. At the top level, give the homepage of your app in this format: `https://<gitname>.github.io/<repo-name>`.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://gitname.github.io/react-app-name",
  ....
}
```

Your React app will be deployed at `/react-app-name`.

To learn more about how to deploy a React app to GitHub Pages, read [this](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages#procedure).

If that was indeed done correctly, you might want to look into specifying the [`basename`](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/api#router) prop in `BrowserRouter` that provides a base URL path for all the locations in the application (as suggested in [@ivanosevitch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71010319/11917891)).

---

If none of the above solves the issue, please elaborate on your problem so it is easier to understand where it is stemming from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using React Router?
Having more info on your routing code and lib, or a link to your code would greatly help.

If you are indeed using React Router, I believe the [`basename` property](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/api#router) would help.

```
  <BrowserRouter basename="react-app-name">
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks, also it didn't work, but I found another 2 solution. One is just replacing the BrowserRouter with HashRouter, or use the basename property like `basenane={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}`. With only the app name like `basenane="react-app"` didn't work.